# Book on changing habits and middot (character traits) improvement?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits

There is now an increasing body of secular literature on how changing habits can help change character (e.g., [The Power of Habit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0055PGUYU), [Atomic Habits](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07D23CFGR/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_C0zjDbZC8F3YV)) but this is not new to us (see Rambam's [Hilchot Deot 1:2 and 1:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910340/jewish/Deot-Chapter-One.htm)). Is there a Jewish codified version of such an approach?

**I am specifically asking for books (ideally in English) focused on *middot* (character traits) improvements**, e.g., recording of lectures or some form of handbook? I'm thinking of a system to perfect oneself, one habit or *midda* at a time.

I know that R [Avigdor Miller](http://Avigdor%20Miller) was running *[musar vaadim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49216/11501)* in that direction and at least [one book](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193783.html) on him describes some of its basic ideas.

[Orchot Tzadikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim) would be an example of a very early book of that type but I am looking for something more contemporary. I know of a number of similar works on prayer and am asking more broadly.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45252/170 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19046/170. A counterpart to this question, looking for earlier-written books: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22465/170. Overlapping with this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13578/170

Comment: Mesillas Yesharim?

Answer (score 3):

I think [Sefer cheshbon hanefesh](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9/) is what you looking for.

[Here](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%9C_%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9F) is a Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 2):

You may also like the [Sefer Orchos Yosher](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/ORCYH.html) by Rav Chaim Kanievsky it was translated by Artscroll.

Answer (score 1):

More non-contemporary works include *Messilat Yesharim* (I think it's called The Path of the Just in English), *Chovot HaLevavot* (Duties of the Heart), *Sha'arei Teshuvah* (Gates of Repentance) and Rabbi Eliyahu Dessler's books, among others.

These classic works are great character builders and I would highly recommend learning them. There may be contemporary works based on these works, too, and classes to study them well.
I believe there's a book of Rabbi Avigdor Miller's lessons on Duties of the Heart.

I think there's a contemporary book called נתיבות המשפט or something like that which I have heard is good.

I think Rabbi Pincus of blessed memory also wrote good books (or they were written from recordings of his lectures following his tragic death).

There are plenty of (Jewish) contemporary books in English, some on specific topics. These include books such as Guard Your Tongue, Love Thy Neighbour, The Gift of Speech and others.
There's a big book on anger, but I don't remember what it is called.

There's a series of small square books, whose names and author I do not remember, on various issues.

A secular book I highly recommend is The Feeling Good Handbook (and various associated books).

Comment: "There's a big book on anger but I don't remember what it is called": maybe this one? https://www.amazon.com/Remove-Anger-Your-Heart-Tolerance/dp/1607630362/ref=sr_1_12?__mk_pt_BR=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&keywords=Torah+Guide&qid=1563285256&s=books&sr=1-12

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to see:

- [The Aleph-Bet Book](https://seforimcenter.com/Latest-100-added-in-ENGLISH/The-Aleph-Bet-book-Sefer-HaMiddot---Rabbi-Nachman-of-Breslov__p-766-11010.aspx) by Rebbe Nachman of Breslov
- and  [Guide to Midoth Improvement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1583300317) by Rabbi Naftali Hoffner.

Answer (score 1):

R Moshe Don Kestenbaum has come up with a very relevant book called [Olam HaMiddos: A guide to understanding ourselves and refining our character](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/OLAMH.html) which artscroll describes as

> Sefer Olam HaMiddos has become a popular and much-read book through
> the Torah world - and for good reason. The author, an acclaimed
> educator, writer, and speaker, combines Torah sources, real-life
> stories, and deep insight into human nature, to show us the nature of
> each midah (character trait) and how improving our middos enables us
> to live full and happy lives.
>
> What is the first step in tikkun hamiddos, refining and perfecting our
> character traits? How do we build our self-worth without becoming
> haughty? Why is being happy such an important part of improving our
> middos? Here are the answers to these and so many more vital
> questions.

See also [here](https://blog.artscroll.com/2019/09/06/artscroll-speaks-with-rabbi-moshe-don-kestenbaum-author-of-olam-hamiddos/) for a brief interview with the author.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avraham Twerski zt"l has a book that deals exactly with what your looking for, entitled *The Enemy Within* and published by [Artscroll](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578197637.html).

Each chapter deal with a different aspect of self-improvement including titles such as, 'Anger', 'Diligence', 'Vanity', 'Belief', 'Pursuit of Truth' etc.

The blurb reads as follows:

> Though we are usually unaware of it, the lines of spiritual battle are drawn early in life and persist till our last day. In this intriguing book, the renowned Rabbi Abraham J. Twerski, M.D. delineates how the tactics of the yetzer hara are carefully tailored to each individual and how tenaciously it attempts to hold us in its grip.
>
> And yet, Rabbi Twerski assures us, we each have the ability to triumph over temptation and live upright Jewish lives. Utilizing Torah wisdom and his deep insight into human psychology, he teaches us to galvanize our spiritual and emotional resources to battle the specific challenges inherent in today's lifestyle.
>
> From common anxiety to oppressive depression, from the rush of daily obligations to the unique family tensions of the "sandwich generation," Rabbi Twerski discusses a broad range of modern ills and helps us feel confident that we can, in fact, strengthen our will and overcome them.